# I need top row of same user RegistrationId Using SQL Query(I need SQL select query)

Tags: sql-server

I have a view and view name is my_view which have below example data and if RegistrationId will duplication means, select top of the row of the user details based on RegistrationId.

My View details.

```
Email                  Qualification      RegistrationId
master@gmail.com       MCA                    101
master@gmail.com       BCA                    101
testing@gmail.com      MBA                    102
```

I need result should be.

```
Email                  Qualification      RegistrationId
master@gmail.com       MCA                    101
testing@gmail.com      MBA                    102
```

Comment: `select top of the row` based on which column? Do you have identity column/create date?

Answer (score 1):

based on Registration ID you can get related results using Row_number

put this code in your View

```
declare @Table1 TABLE 
    (Email varchar(17), Qualification varchar(3), RegistrationId int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Email, Qualification, RegistrationId)
VALUES
    ('master@gmail.com', 'MCA', 101),
    ('master@gmail.com', 'BCA', 101),
    ('testing@gmail.com', 'MBA', 102)
;
```

**Select query**

```
Select Email, Qualification, RegistrationId from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY RegistrationId ORDER BY RegistrationId)RN from @Table1 )T
WHERE T.RN = 1
```

Comment: `ORDER BY RegistrationID` how this will ensure that that it will get `MCA ` and not `BCA`?

Comment: @lad2025 it is giving exact result set what he wants I have tested that in my database

Comment: Great argument. It gives the correct result. What if I will have 10 record with 101 with different result and query optimizer will use parallel execution?

Comment: yes I agree with you @lad2025 but based on his sample data the result have given .If problem persists in future SO is there to help out

Comment: @zahed based on your assumed data it is giving correct result set still you have any problem just tell us we are there to help you ..cheers

Comment: But @lad2025 is telling something, so getting confuse because want to implement into my stored procedure.

Comment: yes @lad2025 is saying using Order by Registration ID will not ensure consistent results and it will create problems if data get bigger

Comment: I need select query, @Jonathan because, view is already created and i have to keep your code into stored procedure, means i am calling stored procedure for displaying.

Comment: @zahed just use the select query don't use table data in the answer.. modified the answer check once

Comment: But you did not mention view_name in your select query. @Jonathan

Comment: @zahed just wrap that code in CREATE VIEW my_view  AS (what ever the code  )

Comment: I paste your query in stored procedure like :    Select Email,GivenName,Nationality,CellPhone,ExperienceYear,Title,RegistrationId from (select *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY RegistrationId ORDER BY RegistrationId)RN from View_Seach_ByPositionIdStatus )T WHERE T.RN = 1 and T.Status=@Status and  T.Qualification=@FilterValue and T.AppliedPositionId=@PositionId

Comment: I am not getting correct result, if you want to see my view then pls check this link: https://forums.asp.net/t/2078301.aspx?Duplicate+items+are+not+added+using+ASP+NET+C+  .